# Reading mails in Blackberry app

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-jde

Is it possible for a Blackberry JDE 4.6 app to read the mails stored on blackberry device?
I don't want to implement a mail client (smtp/pop/imap etc.)
Is there any way to just read the mail already fetched by mail client built into Blackberry OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, have a look at net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Store.